# Connect a Bluetooth device with two different topologies

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, mesh-network, bluetooth-mesh

Is it possible that one device can connect to two different bluetooth topologies and thus process two different connections at the same time?

I have a mesh network to which several devices are connected.
One of the devices should also maintain a connection with an external bluetooth device at the same time.

Would such a thing be theoretically possible or not.
if not, are there any alternative or other ideas?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455560/how-to-make-a-ble-mesh-network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this should be doable. This is because at its core, mesh is an advert-based topology. In your above diagram, think of your green nodes as just devices sending BLE adverts to each other. This means that theoretically it should be possible for one of those devices (or even multiple of them) to be in a connection with other devices (inside or outside the mesh network). The image below shows that this capability is used to extend the range and technologies of a mesh network:-

[image]

I highly recommend going through the links below as they give a good overview of Bluetooth mesh and its evolution from Bluetooth Low Energy:-

- [From BLE to Mesh](https://www.iotforall.com/bluetooth-iot-applications/?__s=jzupqxvcgwykiwq7dgfj&utm_source=drip&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Weekly%20BLE%20Newsletter%20-%20October%2019%2C%202018&utm_content=Weekly%20BLE%20Newsletter%20-%20October%2019%2C%202018)
- [Developing BLE Applications with Mesh](https://www.digikey.com/en/articles/techzone/2018/mar/designing-bluetooth-low-energy-smart-applications-part-1?dclid=COiVrZWVlNwCFciXdwodlasObA)
- [Bluetooth Mesh for Android Developers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KoyVpNpadxE&feature=youtu.be)

I hope this helps.